# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am receving the following error when attemping to bulk insert some data from a datatable to a table in SQL database.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS'.

Specifically, when attempting to execute the statement

```
bcp.WriteToServer(DT)
```

From the routine below

```
Sub DataTableToSQLColMap(Connstring As String, DT As DataTable, SQLTable As String, DTCol() As String, SQLTBLCol() As String)
    Dim i As Integer

    'Create a new SqlBulkCopy class
    Dim bcp As New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(Connstring, _
                SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)

    bcp.DestinationTableName = SQLTable

    '  The default is 30 seconds
    bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 180    '3mins emough?
    bcp.ColumnMappings.Clear()

    For i = 0 To UBound(DTCol, 1)
        bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(DTCol(i), SQLTBLCol(i))
    Next i

    bcp.WriteToServer(DT)
    bcp.Close()
End Sub
```

This has appeared overnight - the code has worked fine for months up until now.  I am using VS2013 (VB.NET) and SSMS 2008.  Windows 7

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - thanks for the reply.  I changed  `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls` to `SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default` and the problem has disappeared.  The KeepNulls was a hangover from a test I was doing.  I'm still none the wiser as to what the problem actually was and why it appeared all of a sudden

Comment: This might help you understand the option ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt621539.aspx